# TypeError: schema[sync ? 'validateSync' : 'validate'] is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, formik, yup

I am trying to validate a material ui form using Formik and Yup but I am getting an error.

This is my schema that I import from another file.

```
export const schema = Yup.object({
  email: Yup.string()
    .email('Invalid Email')
    .required('This Field is Required'),
});
```

This is where I am using the validation. 
If I write `validation = schema`it didn't give an error but there was no validation either. If I change it to `{schema}`the app crashes.

```
export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation(REMOVE_USER);

  let submitForm = (email: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
      variables: {
        email: email,
      },
    })      
  };

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues:{ email: '' },
    onSubmit:(values, actions) => {
       setTimeout(() => {
          alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
          actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        },
       validationSchema:{schema}
    })

    const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>)=>{
      const {name,value} = e.target;
      formik.setFieldValue(name,value);
     }

  return (
    <div>
              <Form
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(formik.values.email);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={formik.touched.email ? formik.errors.email : ''}
                    error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={formik.values.email}
                    //onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                    onChange={formik.handleChange}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <CustomButton
                    disabled={!formik.values.email}
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </Form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Additionally, I also want to pass `isValid!`condition in the `disabled`of the button but I can't figure out how to do so. I got it in  since I could write it in the props but not sure how to use it in useFormik().

Also, when I submit the form, it the text-fields aren't reset automatically. How could I fix that?

Error:

```
TypeError: schema[sync ? 'validateSync' : 'validate'] is not a function. (In 'schema[sync ? 'validateSync' : 'validate'](validateData, {
    abortEarly: false,
    context: context
  })', 'schema[sync ? 'validateSync' : 'validate']' is undefined)
```

Earlier on, I was using `<Formik>`. In this case, the validation was done while I was typing, for instance if I write 'hfs' it will tell me invalid email immediately while I am typing. However, with useFormik (acc to the answer below), it says invalid email only after I submit the form. I don't want to happen because once the form is submitted, the mutation is called as well. I want to keep the validation separate. This is what I was using earlier

```
export default function RemoveUserPage() {
  const [isSubmitted, setIsSubmitted] = useState(false);
  const [isRemoved, setIsRemoved] = useState(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = useState('');

  const [removeUser] = useMutation<DeleteUserResponse>(REMOVE_USER);

  let submitForm = (email: string) => {
    setIsSubmitted(true);
    removeUser({
      variables: {
        email: email,
      },
    })
      .then(({ data }: ExecutionResult<DeleteUserResponse>) => {
        if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
          setIsRemoved(true);
        }
      })
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{ email: '' }}
        onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
            actions.setSubmitting(false);
          }, 1000);
        }}
        validationSchema={schema}>
        {props => {
          const {
            values: { email },
            errors,
            touched,
            handleChange,
            isValid,
            setFieldTouched,
          } = props;
          const change = (name: string, e: FormEvent) => {
            e.persist();
            handleChange(e);
            setFieldTouched(name, true, false);
          };
          return (
            <Wrapper>
              <Form
                onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(email);
                }}>
                <div>
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    margin="normal"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    helperText={touched.email ? errors.email : ''}
                    error={touched.email && Boolean(errors.email)}
                    label="Email"
                    value={email}
                    onChange={change.bind(null, 'email')}
                  />
                  <br></br>
                  <CustomButton
                    disabled={!isValid || !email}
                    text={'Remove User'}
                  />
                </div>
              </Form>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `useFormik`? Where is it declared?

Comment: I guess it should be `validationSchema: schema` instead of `validationSchema:{schema}`.

Comment: Wdym by where it's declared? It's ```import { useFormik } from 'formik';``` and I have mentioned the initial values (email) @Bergi

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be validationSchema: schema instead of {schema}

The reason why it doesn't validate is that you don't use formik's handleSubmit

```
useFormik({
initialValues:{ email: '' },
onSubmit:(values, actions) => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      actions.setSubmitting(false);
      }, 1000);
    },
   validationSchema: schema
})

...

<Form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
  ...
  <CustomButton
       disabled={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email ? true : false}
       text={'Remove User'}
  />
  ...
</Form>
```

It should use formik's handleSubmit to get the validation what you define on validationSchema

Also pass the formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email to disabled prop of the button.

Based on your request, to validate the field when you type, you should do as the following:

```
<TextField
        variant="outlined"
        margin="normal"
        id="email"
        name="email"
        helperText={formik.touched.email ? formik.errors.email : ""}
        error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
        label="Email"
        value={formik.values.email}
        onChange={props => {
          formik.handleChange(props);
          formik.handleBlur(props);
        }}
        onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      />
```

Comment: I am also calling another function in my onSubmit. Is it not possible to use Formik's handleSubmit and my SubmitForm() function together? I tried this, but there's no validation: ```onSubmit={e => {
                  e.preventDefault();
                  submitForm(formik.values.email);
                  formik.handleSubmit();
                }}>```

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work if I use ```onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}```either. So maybe it's something else that I am missing out

Comment: Is your CustomButton's type 'submit'?

Comment: Yup, it's submit

Comment: Can you check the console inside the Form onSubmit if it is handled?
<Form onSubmit={() => { console.log('hello') } }>

Comment: Ah it works when I submit the form but not when I am typing. I want't facing this issue while I used <Formik> but can't make it work properly in useFormik. Could you see the updated qs? Also, the disabled field doesn't work. It runs the mutation even when the email is invalid.

Comment: try to use your submitForm function inside the formik's onSubmit. Right now you call your submitForm on Form's onSubmit and it should call without the validation. That's the reason. You can call your submitForm after passing the validation by calling inside the formik's onSubmit

Comment: Do you mean I should call submitForm inside Formik's handleSubmit? How can I see & modify the Formik's onSubmit definition?

Comment: I mean, you can call your submitForm inside the setTimeout
By the way, if you can lead me to code-sandbox, I am willing to fix on there

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-dawn-es7k4 here or whatever you want

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-hooks-2mdwm?file=/src/App.tsx Here, I tried calling submitForm inside the timeout but the problem remains the same. It doesn't do the validation while I am typing and it only shows once I submit. It would be great if you could look into this issue. Thanks!!

Comment: you want the validation while you are typing? then it should be implemented differently. let me check the code sandbox

Comment: I added onBlur={formik.handleBlur} and it seems works. Please check

Comment: please check my updated answer below your qs. Also I updated on codesandbox.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was because of not providing `yup.object` for validationSchema object so I solved it like this :

```
 const addUserValidationSchema = yup.object({
   ....
 })
```